# Downloading a list of files using wget from an index.html url

Tags: wget

I'm working through a data analytics course and part of it requires downloading a list of files. I've spent more time trying to figure out how to do it with wget that I could have just downloaded them individaully, but now it's become a learning experience. This is the url of the files

https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

Every file is a zip file, so I've tried using

wget -r -l1 -H -t1 -nd -A.zip -erobots=off https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com/ and with /index.html

But everytime the only file it downloades is an index.html.tmp which in then automatically removes. Any ideas?

SOLUTION: After way too much time, I realized that the page was using jquery to display the links and so get wasn't actually able to locate the links on index.html. The solution to make this work is below:

```
wget https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com/ -q -O - |
```

This pulls the XML data from the index.html page

```
grep -Eoi '<Key>[^>]+</Key>' |
```

Strips everything except the key tag which contained the filename and is the proper end of the URL to download the file

```
grep -Eoi '[2D].*.zip' |
```

All the files needed started with either 2 or a D, this pulled just the name of the file and stripped the  tag.

```
sed 's/^/https\:\/\/divvy\-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com\//' > linksfinal.txt
```

Adds in the first part of the URL and saves into a text file.

```
wget -i linksfinal.txt
```

Runs wget using the newly formed links in the file which downloaded all the files with no issues.

Comment: What will happend if you allow greater depth? For example replace `-l1` using `--level=3`

Comment: Unfortunately it wasn't working either. BUT, I've just realized that it's because the links are pulled dynamically through jquery, so when wget searches it doesn't find the links. I'll post a solution in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION: After way too much time, I realized that the page was using jquery to display the links and so get wasn't actually able to locate the links on index.html. The solution to make this work is below:

```
wget https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com/ -q -O - |
```

This pulls the XML data from the index.html page

```
grep -Eoi '<Key>[^>]+</Key>' |
```

Strips everything except the key tag which contained the filename and is the proper end of the URL to download the file

```
grep -Eoi '[2D].*.zip' |
```

All the files needed started with either 2 or a D, this pulled just the name of the file and stripped the tag.

```
sed 's/^/https\:\/\/divvy\-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com\//' > linksfinal.txt
```

Adds in the first part of the URL and saves into a text file.

```
wget -i linksfinal.txt
```

Runs wget using the newly formed links in the file which downloaded all the files with no issues.